# invalide username or password when validate it sqlite iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

when Click on update button then data does not updated i want to just updated my password

> first match old password
>   if old  password match with database then validate new password and conform password using isEquelToString then click on update button and oldpassword must be updated with newPassword

Comment: @hello Nitin, i did not get your code in my answer. where is it?

Comment: check main question i adit and put code there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think user name and password match for single user only there for if it match then it will return one row using following code. Check the following code i think this will work for you.

```
-(void)checkingDatabase{

    databaseName = @"trylogin.sqlite";


// Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName]retain];
    NSLog(@"databse path %@",databasePath);

    database = nil;




    int myInt = 0;
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) ==SQLITE_OK){
        NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select COUNT(*) from loginTry where userName='%@' and password='%@'",txtusername.text,txtPassword.text];
        const char *sqlStatement = [tempSQL cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [tempSQL release];

        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;  

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL); 
        if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) { 
            myInt = (int)sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 0);
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement); 
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
    if(myInt ! = 0){
        AnimalViewController *FBController = [[AnimalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnimalViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.view addSubview:FBController.view]; 

    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Wrong username or password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i done it but now i am creating change password control...first i match old password then second text filed is new password and third is conform password i match old password but cant update new password any idea...?

Comment: Are you implementing this feature after successful login or before login in to application?

Comment: in My applicaiton i am successfully inserted data and login too now i put one Button(change password) on login view and by clicking of Button user redirect change password View and there i am implementing this feature like first old password must be match First textFild
then if new password and conform password both are match then new password will be updated by clicking button(update) in current database i hope you are understood what i am saying...?

Comment: You have to interact with database two time, first you have to check user name and password is matching or not if it matching then you have to check new password and confirm password are same if it is same then you have to interact with database again for update password of that username.

Comment: you mean i use nested query...?first is select password from table name where password = @"?" or in this query i am using second update quety update password set password where primary_key = '?';

Comment: thank you Hidden but i Implemented  Your code but yet not updated my old password i am attached my code with your answer please check my code and telme please what's wrong and where is my mistack

Answer (score 2):

As above same but some change at condition checking as follows..

```
if(myInt ! = 0) {
    if([newpassword.text isEqualToString: confirmPassword.text]) {
        //Write code for update query.
    }
    else {
        //print message new password and confirm password does not match.
    }
}
else 
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Wrong username or password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Comment: i just except your answer today sorry for delay.. :)